# Android: How do I return a selected dataset from SimpleAdapter via onclick?

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to get my head round using SimpleAdapter however I am struggling with one item.

How do I return the array of data for the selected view?

Here is the code I use to generate it.

```
// Data for List Adapter
List<Map<String, Object>> resourceNames = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

// Make Hashmap of Results Hashmaps
generateData(resourceNames);

//Source information from Hashmap keys (FROM)
String keynames[]={"names","descriptions"};

// Target Views for Data (TO) 
int[] targets = new int[] { R.id.textfield_name,R.id.textfield_description};

// Create my Simple Adapter
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, resourceNames,
        R.layout.listrow, keynames,targets
        );

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

}

I then use an onclick listener to get the data using the following code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.listview);


final ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(arg1.getContext(),
                getString(R.string.selected) + " " + position,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // How do I return the entire data that I used                  
        }
});
```

I can see above how I get the position of the data in the array- but how do I return the actual results data being shown in the view??

Comment: Is it me, or why can't you just do `resourceNames.get(position)` to get the data that you want?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch `keynames array` value when it get selected, right? if yes, then simple do this `resourceNames.get(position)` it will return selected value.

Comment: I couldn't see resourcenames in the onclick listener- but if I changed to a field, it now works! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `List<Map<String, Object>> resourceNames = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();`

globally and in ListView's `onItemClick()` just put line,

```
Map<String, Object> map = resourceNames.get(position);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had to also assign it as a field in the class, as otherwise it wasn't visible to the onclick.  Ie changed: List<Map<String, Object>> resourceNames = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(); to this.resourceNames=( same as before)